# Rails confirm not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there are a few posts around but I cannot for the life of me see where I am going wrong.  I am running Ruby on Rails and am trying to execute the following code:

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article),
          method: :delete,
          data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

My gemfile is loading jquery-rails.

My layout looks like this

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "defaults" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

I don't see any confirm box at all, and thus I can't click any buttons to forward the delete method.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT (layout)

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Comment: can you please post your `defaults` js file.

Comment: Do you import turbolinks in your js file?

Comment: Does the article get deleted?

Comment: The article does not get deleted.  I have since changed my layout to the above edit and there is still an issue.

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem: downgrade your coffee-script in your gem file.
to:

gem 'coffee-script-source', '~> 1.8.0'

run bundle update

and restart server.

coffee-script 1.10 it's not compatible with current rails version, i think? cheers.

Comment: I'm still having an issue.  Is this line a possible issue?  `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>`  Also should I have anything particular in application.js?

Comment: Nope, at first i thought it was the problem. if you change 'application' to 'default' if would work, but not recommended. another solution is so use button_to but it wont confirm. I solve this problem by my solution above. also try disabling adblock and make sure your browser javascript is on.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out...or at least corrected it.  I had had old code in my application.js that was interfearing with jquery